# I was not getting sign in and signup button in one line for navigation bar when trying to clone Usabilityhub website

Tags: html, css, frontend, uinavigationbar, navbar

I was unable to make sign in button and other navigation links in the same line.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&family=Ubuntu&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin-inline: 50px;
}


/* top section*/

header {
  background: #e74694;
  background-image: url(./asset\ 32.png);
  background-size: 22%;
}

.top-section {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/* nav section*/

.logo img {
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  gap: 40px;
}

.navsection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.nav-links ul {
  justify-content: end;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Signin {
  border: 0.5px solid #b9cde4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #183b56;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

.links {
  padding: 12px 24px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<!--top section-->
<header>
  <div class="top-section container">
    <p>  Figma prototype testing just got a whole lot better! Read more → </p>

  </div>
</header>

<!--Navigation section-->
<div class="navsection container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a>
      <img src="./asset 1.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="links">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="links">Customers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="links">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="links">Resources</a></li>
      <li class="Signin"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      <li class="Signup"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Signin button was not coming in the same link as other links when using border and padding [Sign in button was not on same line as other nav links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68WOJ.png)
[this is desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3z5v.png)
I was unable to get signin button and other li tags in same line when using border , padding for it .

Comment: Have you tried adding `padding` and `border` for `.Signup` as well?

Comment: No , I only tried for .Signin .

Comment: Then you should try doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I completely changed **nav section** and **html** codes now works fine . You can control them with below codes. If you don't want to change codes you can add this code only. But in this situation header background not works fine.

```css
.nav-links > ul > li > a {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&family=Ubuntu&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin-inline: 50px;
}

/* top section*/

header {
  background-color: #e74694;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}

.top-section {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* nav section*/
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

.nav > li {
  display: Inline-block;
  padding: 10px 9px 10px 9px;
}

.nav > li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(46, 11, 243);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}

.Signin {
  border: 0.5px solid #b9cde4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #183b56;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.Signup {
  border: 0.5px solid #b9cde4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #183b56;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--top section-->
    <header>
      <div class="top-section container">
        <p> Figma prototype testing just got a whole lot better! Read more →</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
    <!--Navigation section-->
    <div id='nav'>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/75/75" id="logo"  />

      <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#" class="links">Product</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="links">Customers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="links">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="links">Resources</a></li>
          <li class="Signin"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li></span>
          <li class="Signup"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li></span>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```